# Is Parallel Testing possible in Cucumber with TestNG?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, testng, cucumber, bdd

I am trying to implement Cucumber in my current project with TestNG and I need to execute my script parallely on multiple browsers.

> Is Parallel Testing possible in Cucumber? If Yes, Can any one help me any reference links or Code to perform Parallel Testing in Cucumber?

Comment: Google turned up [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778361/i-am-unable-to-run-cucumber-jvm-test-in-selenium-grid-in-parallel) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778361/i-am-unable-to-run-cucumber-jvm-test-in-selenium-grid-in-parallel).  To see the simplest cucumber-jvm/TestNG configuration you can look [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/java-calculator-testng).  cucumber-testng uses the JUnit test runner so I would say yes.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://automatictester.co.uk/2015/06/11/basic-cucumberjvm-selenium-webdriver-test-automation-framework/) shows how. "TestNG" is used to enable parallel execution on runner level.

Comment: I got the project referenced in the answer link to run locally. Pretty slick. TestNG test runners are used; not JUnit test runners.